# How well does SSRS End User Designer work?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to figure out if this tool will be good enough for my non-technical users to build reports themselves.  I know they will need to have a lot of business/domain knowledge about the data model I present them.  But how about the UI itself?

Has anyone used the [SSRS Report Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917530.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120) in this way?  What is your experience with it?

Building and (mostly) maintaining the data model seems like it will take a good deal of development effort.  Any tips with this?  Know any good places to look for reference?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the level of understanding of the users. As you said, the users need to understand the layout of the data. They also need to understand basic query concepts (filtering, grouping, sorting etc.). Once they have that, it is easy to create reports with Report Builder. It is literally drag and drop, although for more complex queries I recommend to users that we build the reports for them.  I suggest having a play with it yourself. My main reason for not letting users loose with Report Builder is that (AFAIK) there is no way to change the default report template (reports need to fit in with corporate fonts, colours etc.).

As far as the data model, it is pretty simple to set up and, provided your database schema doesn't change, requires no maintenance. Once the tables, joins etc are defined, that's it. Books Online have some good walkthroughs [here](http://link.phillip.pe/SSRSDataModelTutorial).